# Will I lose the "Kingsoul" charm?

Tags: hollow-knight

The [Hollow Knight Wiki](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Kingsoul) states:

(Spoilers for the 2nd and 3rd endings!)

> This charm is primarily only equipped to unlock the secret area at the bottom of the Abyss, after which it is **permanently replaced** by Void Heart.

Similarly, on the wiki page about the other charm, it states:

> This charm replaces Kingsoul and cannot be unequipped. However, it no longer has Kingsoul's effects, nor does it use any notches.

Does this mean that once I unlock the Void Heart charm, I can no longer use the Kingsoul charm?

Comment: Generally, your question needs to make sense without the spoilers.  If it doesn't, then it shouldn't be in spoilers.

Comment: @Frank I've never heard that before. Do you have a meta link on that topic? Either way, I think my last sentence, `Does this mean that once I unlock the Void Heart charm, I can no longer use the Kingsoul charm?` nicely summarizes the question itself, spoiler or not

Comment: We don't want a summary.  We want a *question*.  I haven't played this game, but our stance stems from the fact that we don't coddle users here.  Don't beat around the bush.  Just ask your question.  For more information, see [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/of-spoilers-plot-twists-and-our-mission)

Comment: @Frank I suggest you re-read the meta question's top voted answer, particularly this part: "Spoiler markup in a clearly spoilery question is often necessary to prevent spoilers from being visible in the question excerpt. Don't know if there is a better way to do that."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my own playthrough, I can tell you that you permanently lose the Kingsoul charm as soon as you unlock the Void Heart charm... Void Heart even replaces Kingsoul in the Charm screen.

Having said that, I haven't played through the game since it originally launched and I'm not sure if the Hidden Dreams, Grimm Troupe, or the (currently in beta) Lifeblood DLCs have changed this.  I suspect they haven't since the event where you gain the Void Heart is a major plot event.

Comment: Man. What a bummer that such a powerful and useful charm must be permanently destroyed to defeat the end boss.

Comment: @GeoHam I know, it kinda bugged me too.  Having said that, you can be smart (unlike me) and keep it for the Colosseum of Fools.

Comment: With 5 charm notches and painfully slow soul regeneration, Kingsoul usability is very limited - it takes 16 to 18 seconds to produce enough SOUL to heal or cast a spell (12 with Spell Twister), and it's acquired very late into the game. Regeneration this painfully slow is nearly never better than the alternatives (Hiveblood+Joni's Blessing for infinite healing, Grubsong+Soul Catcher/Eater+Dream Wielder for improved SOUL gain, Shaman Stone and Spell Twister for 'more bang for the buck', more efficient use of SOUL in combat.